# TensorFlow: How to find minimum/maximum coordinates of segmentations in a tensor excluding zeros?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, image-segmentation

For the computation of Intersection over Union (IoU) I want to find coordinates of minimum and maximum values (the border pixels) in a segmentation image `image_pred` that is represented by a float32 3D tensor. In particular, I aim at finding top left and bottom right corner coordinates of objects in an image. The image is entirely comprised of black pixels (value 0.0) except where the object is located, I have color pixels (0.0 < values < 1.0). Here's an example for such a bounding box (in my case, the object is the traffic sign and the environment is blacked out):

[image]

My approach so far is to `tf.boolean_mask` for setting every pixel to False except for the color pixels:

```
zeros = tf.zeros_like(image_pred)
mask = tf.greater(image_pred, zeros)
boolean_mask_pred = tf.boolean_mask(image_pred, mask)
```

and then use `tf.where` to find the coordinates of the masked image. To determine the **horizontal and vertical coordinate values** of the top left and bottom right corners of the rectangle, I thought about using `tf.recude_max` and `tf.reduce_min`, but since these do not return a single value if I provide an `axis`, I am unsure if this is the correct function to use. According to the docs, if I do not specify `axis`, the function will reduce all dimensions which is not what I want either. Which is the correct function to do this? The IoU in the end is a single 1D float value.

```
coordinates_pred = tf.where(boolean_mask_pred)
x21 = tf.reduce_min(coordinates_pred, axis=1)
y21 = tf.reduce_min(coordinates_pred, axis=0)
x22 = tf.reduce_max(coordinates_pred, axis=1)
y22 = tf.reduce_max(coordinates_pred, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is not use `tf.boolean_mask`. First, I customized a similar picture.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = np.zeros(shape=(256,256))
np.random.seed(0)
image[12:76,78:142] = np.random.random_sample(size=(64,64))
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Then get its the coordinates of maximum and minimum by tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf

image_pred = tf.placeholder(shape=(256,256),dtype=tf.float32)
zeros = tf.zeros_like(image_pred)
mask = tf.greater(image_pred, zeros)

coordinates_pred = tf.where(mask)
xy_min = tf.reduce_min(coordinates_pred, axis=0)
xy_max = tf.reduce_max(coordinates_pred, axis=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(xy_min,feed_dict={image_pred:image}))
    print(sess.run(xy_max,feed_dict={image_pred:image}))

[12 78]
[ 75 141]
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have clarified: I'm interested in finding the coordinates of the upper left and lower right corner of the bounding box surrounding the segmentation pixels (>0) in the image. I changed the question a little bit to make this more obvious.

Comment: @FábioFerreira I don't quite understand what you need. Is it the `coordinates` of `min/max` or the value of `min/max`? Can you add an example of input and except output?

Comment: the coordinates of min/max. I clarified above